# TrustedInstaller Preventing Deletion of Files/Folders

Tags: file-permissions, x86

I'm looking to free up space on my computer by deleting some unnecessary files and folders I found in Program Files (x86). A problem I came across was a "Folder Access Denied" where it stated that I'll need permission from "TrustedInstaller" in order to make changes to the folder. Is there any way to circumvent this issue without making major permissions changes?

Comment: What specifically are these "unnecessary files and folders"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options if you want to list/change the content of a folder where only TrustedInstaller has permissions:

1. Take ownership of the folder, then assign full permissions to yourself.
2. Use a tool that circumvents the Windows security model by using the backup and restore privileges. My program [SetACL Studio](http://helgeklein.com/setacl-studio/) does that when listing, i.e. it displays everything regardless of permissions. I do not know of any tool that deletes files this way, though.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Your program, SetACL, looks very ingenious but it appears that the permissions problems I have may just be because I'm trying to get rid of IE7 and WinDefender. Unsure if you can really delete these as I think they only can be turned off? I'm going to ask another question as addendum to this one because I came across something else interesting while trying to manage/change permissions. Thanks again.